# Call getMethod with a subclass as method argument

Tags: java, reflection, subclass, invoke, superclass

Is it possible to invoke a method where the argument object or the argument class is a subclass and the method himself took the superclass as argument?

I trying to invoke this method `public void setNewProblem(Problem problem);` with a concrete implementation of the abstract class Problem. Unfortunately I get an `NoSuchMethodException` exception.

I call the invoke like this:

```
Method method = model.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, new Class[] { newValue.getClass() });
method.invoke(model, newValue);
```

If I change `newValue.getClass()` to `Problem.class` everything works fine. Any idea how to  pass a subclass to `public void setNewProblem(Problem problem);`?

Comment: The exception is not caused by invoke(). It's caused by getMethod(). You need the actual declared class to find the method in the class. But you may pass any subclass instance when invoking the method. Almost every time reflection is used, it shouldn't. There's probably a better way to achieve what you want than reflection. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, the exception is caused by getMethod(), maybe I was unclear there. I use [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) MVC implementation. In this implementation the controller use invoke to tell the model what has changed in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ask for the exact type it is.  This is because you can have multiple possible overloaded methods and it needs to know exact what you wanted.

So you can invoke with a sub-class but you cannot ask for a sub-class without be being there.

What you can do is look at all methods and find a match.

If all you need is the setter or getter for a property, I suggest you look at [BeanIntrospector](http://geti.dcc.ufrj.br/cursos/fes_2008_1/javatutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) which will find you all the properties and the getter/setter methods for that property.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know, which problem is added to model. It could be ProblemX, ProblemY or ProblemZ.

Comment: @hofmeister You don't need to know which instance type it is,you only need to know the type of the method.

Comment: Yea, your right. ProblemX instance of Problem should be enough to set the correct arguments for getMethod()?

Comment: Calling setNewProblem(Problem) is enough for any sub-class of Problem. Are you sure you need refection at all?

Comment: Probably this is the best solution. Change the MVC and throw the reflection away.

Comment: @hofmeister Using reflection leads to a host of problems you are better off without if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `newValue.getClass()` is a subclass of the class in the declared method.

From `Class.getMethod`:

> To find a matching method in a class C:  If C declares exactly one
>   public method with the specified name and exactly the same formal
>   parameter types, that is the method reflected.

You could work your way up the inheritance chain until it works:

```
Method getMethod(Class c1, Class c2) {
    if(c2.getSuperClass() == null) {
        return c1.getMethod("set" + propertyName, new Class[] { c2 });
    }
    try {
        return c1.getMethod("set" + propertyName, new Class[] { c2 });
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return getMethod(c1, c2.getSuperClass());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Method method = getMethod(model.getClass(), newValue.getClass());
```

I hesitate to suggest this, however, since it does not cover 100% of cases (such as if the formal argument class is an interface), and the way you are doing this is bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Class.getMethod()` you have to specify correctly the *formal* argument types. Not the types of the actual arguments you are planning to supply. You have to match precisely what it says in the declaration of the method concerned.

["The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)